# Unknown number of user input integers

Tags: c

So the second part of my homework this week is to: Write a program that accepts an arbitrary number of positive integers, supplied by
the user, and then prints out the highest and lowest integer, as well as the average
of these two. The program should accept data until the user signals that data entry is
complete by entering a negative value.
The program should use the functions from Assignment 1, i.e. one which returns the
larger of two integer arguments, one that returns the lower of two integers, and one
which returns the average.

I am so far out of my depth here it is unbelievable. Extremely worried about this module as it doesn't seem to be sinking in for me. :(

I can's seem to figure out how to do this with an unknown number of integers. Currently the program throws up a strange result.

My code so far is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int getLo(int num1, int num2); 
int getHi(int num1, int num2);
float getAv(int num1, int num2);

int main() 
{
    int num1, num2;
    int count=0,i;
    int *storedNumb;

    printf("Enter the amount of integers you would like to enter:\n\n\n\n");
    scanf("%d", &count);

    printf("Enter %d positive integers:\n", count);

     storedNumb= (int *) calloc(count,sizeof(int));

    for(i=0; i<count; ++i)
    {
        scanf("%d",&storedNumb[i]);
        printf("\nYou entered %d\n",storedNumb[i]);
    }

    float avg = getAv(num1, num2);

    if (num1 <= 0){ // if statement prompting a positive input
        printf("Please enter POSITIVE integers!\n");
        return 0;}
        else if (num2 <= 0){
                printf("Please enter POSITIVE integers!\n");
                return 0;
                }


    printf("The smallest number you entered is: %d\n", getLo(num1, num2));
    printf("The largest number you entered is: %d\n", getHi(num1, num2));
    printf("%.2f is the average of the integers you entered\n", avg);

    return 0;

}

float getAv(int num1, int num2)
{
    return (num1 + num2) / 2.;
}

int getLo(int num1, int num2)
{
    if (num1 < num2)
    {
        return num1;
    }
    else
    {
        return num2;
    }
}

int getHi(int num1, int num2)
{
    if (num1 > num2)
    {
        return num1;
    }
    else
    {
        return num2;
    }

}
```

Comment: What's the strange result the program throws up?

Comment: Do you really need to store all of the values?

Comment: Hi, here is the result 

Enter the amount of integers you would like to enter:



4
Enter 4 positive integers:
6

You entered 6

4

You entered 4
9

You entered 9
7

You entered 7
The smallest number you entered is: 88
The largest number you entered is: 4201024
2100556.00 is the average of the integers you entered

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 35.329 s
Press any key to continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something along the lines of

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int lo, hi, input;
    scanf("\n%d", &input);
    if(input >= 0) {
        hi = input;
        lo = input;
        while(input >= 0) {
            if(input > hi) {
                hi = input;
            }
            if(input < lo) {
                lo = input;
            }
            scanf("\n%d", &input);
        }
    }
    printf("\nlo:%d", lo);
    printf("\nhi:%d", hi);
    printf("\navg:%d", (hi + lo)/2);
    return 0;
}
```